# Configuration for NASA ISLE deployment

Tags: web-server, server, apache-httpd, mysql

NASA has released an open-source version of it's lab inventory system known as ISLE: https://github.com/nasa/isle

I went through the local setup using Vagrant but I was wondering if it would be possible to use the Raspberry Pi as a server for this without using Vagrant.

I'm really new to anything like this and I'm not sure if it's even possible or where to get started. I have installed the required versions of PHP, MySQL, and Apache, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: With the source and editing the init script you can get it to working, just make sure everything points to where you've cloned it to (it assumes /var/www/ so if you put it elsewhere, or in a subfolder, make sure you change it) That's as far as I got, every time I went to the page, I would get a really unhelpful Oops message and a file bug report link. Should've looked at was in that bug report now that I think about it... Maybe tomorrow